# CFIncludes best-practice and potential security concerns

Tags: security, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I am writing an application which includes a number of dialog/modal divs that allow users to perform a variety of tasks e.g. upload image, send email etc.

My application has role-based security so when you are logged in it checks your session variables to find out who you are and then offers up the appropriate features.

At the moment I have all my dialogs/modals within the page that requires them. This means that if I want to use the same dialog box elsewhere in my website, I have to copy the code and put it on that page. This immediately made me think that I should:

1. Create a .cfm file for each dialog box e.g. `imageupload.cfm` and `emailsend.cfm`
2. Include these .cfm files using `<cfinclude>` on which ever page wants to use them

This potential solution causes me challenges because the page which will include the dialog boxes has many if/else statements to work out what to present to which user depending on their role (stored in a session variable).

So do I have to:

1. Duplicate the if/else logical statements to the dialog box pages as well because the
   content served from `imageupload.cfm` for example will be different depending on your role
2. Every page in the site is protected by the invoking a `user-security.cfc` file that checks that the user is logged in. Do I also have to make this call in every dialog box .cfm page? If I do this then there will be two invokes to the same `user-security.cfc` file within the same page because the dialog box page is being included in the main page. But if I don't invoke `user-security.cfc` from within the dialog box .cfm as well, then could someone go directly to those pages and start causing chaos?

Apologies that this is not a pure programming question and more theoretical best practice, but I'm not sure how to tackle it while keeping it scalable. I am using ColdFusion 10 on IIS 7.5

Comment: From where are you invoking the user-security.cfc?

Comment: I *suspect* you should read up on MVC principles and have a look at frameworks already out there (FW/1, Coldbox etc) as it sounds to me like you're possibly reinventing the wheel here a bit.

Comment: @DanBracuk I am invoking user-security.cfc from every single page in the website, except a few which are available to users before they are logged in (e.g. registration page).

Comment: @AdamCameron I'm trying not to use CF frameworks because I need to know 100% how the whole application works. This might sound odd or a non-issue, but its important to me due to how the application will grow over time. More and more 'modules' will be added to it and I need to know exactly where to look to fix an issue. I don't trust a layer of abstraction helping me even though it may 'fix' the issue quicker.

Comment: I think that's a particularly poor approach, shows poor judgement and just making unnecessary work for yourself. And - given you seem to be a relative newbie to this - will result in a less optimal solution. Still: your call. One can only lead a horse to water.

Comment: Not using a framework because you don't know exactly how it works is like refusing to drive a car because you don't know exactly how an internal combustion engine works. Frameworks solve a problem EVERY web application will have. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I would hazard a guess that the code written by framework authors, and used and tested by hundreds of developers, would be more trustworthy than the 'homegrown' framework you are putting together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can increase your code reuseability as follows.

Create an application scope variable with an instance of your user-security.cfc file.  Do this in the onApplicationStart() method of your Application.cfc file.  Something like this:

```
application.SecurityChecker = CreateObject("component", "user-security");
```

Also in your onApplicationStart() method, create a list of pages that do not require a sercurity check.

```
application.SecurityNotNeededPages="page1.cfm,page2.cfm,etc";
```

Use these variables in your onRequestStart() method.

```
var ThisPage = listlast(cgi.PATH_INFO, "/");
if (ListFindNoCase(application.SecurityNotNeededPages, ThisPage) is false) {
application.SecurityChecker.CheckSecurityMethod(argumentcollection = session);
etc
```

This will solve the problem of people browsing directly to included pages if they are not logged in.  It will also make your application run faster because you only have to create an instance of the user-security.cfc once, and it will be available for every user on every page request.

**Edit starts here**

In the comments, Adam Cameron says, "Also, onRequestStart() already receives the name of the file being requested as an argument; there's no need to use the CGI scope to get it, I think".  That was news to me so I thought I'd check it out.

I ran a page that had this function.

```
<cffunction name="onRequestStart" access="public" returntype="boolean">
<cfdump var="#arguments#">
<cfreturn true>
</cffunction>
```

That gave me a key of 1, and value showing the path to the page I actually ran.  So, doing things in the wrong order, I read [the docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7d41.html).  Following those guidelines, I added this to the code above:

```
<cfargument name="targetPage" required="yes">
```

Not surprisingly, the dump gave a key of TARGETPAGE with the same value.  Then I changed the name of the argument to "fred".  The dump gave me a key of FRED with the same value.

The bottom line is, whether you use the argument sent to the page, or the cgi scope, you'll still have to use ListLast to get the name of the page.

Comment: The "included" files should not be in a web-browseable directory in the first place. Only files intended to be browsed to should be in the website directory. *Generally* this would only be index.cfm. Also, `onRequestStart()` already receives the name of the file being requested as an argument; there's no need to use the CGI scope to get it, I think.

Comment: thanks for that Dan very useful. Can I ask why make an object of the user-security component and not just invoke it in the `onRequestStart()` function?

Comment: Because a function should do *one thing* if poss. `onRequestStart()` should prep the request environment, which might involve making calls to security-check code, but it should not actually *contain* the security check code.

Comment: Thanks Adam. I've discovered that if you try to invoke from within the onRequestStart() function, it falls over in IE (works in Firefox). Using the createObject method and it works fine in IE and Firefox.

Comment: in ColdFusion 10 you can create your object like this `application.SecurityChecker = new user-security();` You may need to change `user-security` to `user_security`

Comment: When you use the cfinvoke tag you create an instance of the component every time.  That is less efficient than creating it once.

Comment: @volumeone... `onRequestStart()` runs on the ColdFusion server. CF never talks to the browser, so it never knows that the browser is IE or Firefox. So whatever causes things to work / not work in a browser is nothing to do with the code you have in `onRequestStart()`. I'm not disputing something is amiss, but I don't it is what you think it is.

Comment: @DanBracuk... you've the only one who's mentioned `<cfinvoke>` here. To what are you referring? And, err... one *can* reuse an existing object with `<cfinvoke>`. The `component` attribute will take an object reference as well as a CFC reference.

Comment: @DanBracuk Seconding Adam's comment. Who is using `cfinvoke`?

Comment: The reference to cfinvoke comes from volume one's first comment to this answer.  Perhaps my interpretation is unique.

Answer (score 1):

Create an index.cfm page basically consisting of a big switch statement. Your URLs are action.subaction ie index.cfm?action=email.send. Parse that in the index.cfm. Then for each case, check the security rules and cfinclude as needed. But yeah you really need to learn a framework. FW/1 will do what you want and it's easy to learn. I believe Coldbox has a minimalist version also.

Answer (score 0):

`<cfinclude>` will work on any file with any extension. As a standard practicce, I name all my includes `*.cfi`.

In the FW/1 world this is particularly useful.

I can have directory with

```
views/reports/home.cfm
views/reports/details.cfm
views/reports/header.cfi
```

Valid links include

```
index.cfm/reports/home
index.cfm/reports/details
```

But

```
index.cfm/reports/header
```

does nothing

Doing this communicates to other developers what I intend for the file to do.

Comment: Do your include .cfi files contain any if/else logic within them so they serve the appropriate header information to the correct role of the user? For example, say an Administrator needs server information in their header but a Sales person only wants to see the current datetime. How would you ensure this worked?

Comment: Those conditional headers should be handled by *separate files*. You should have one view file for [the stuff], and other view files for [header] and [footer] files. Seriously... you're level of understanding on how all stuff works would be *greatly* improved by reading up on MVC and just *using a framework*. You'll get more out of it than floundering around the way you are now.

Comment: @JamesMohler... why use non-standard file extensions? If you advocate this advice (which I don't think you should), you should also make sure you specifically advocate never having these files in a web-browseable directory, or making *certain* the web server knows *not* to serve .CFI files. Otherwise a person could browse to your .cfi file, and see all your source code. This is a security hole waiting to happen.

Comment: One should you a non standard extension, so that there will be files with ColdFusion code that will not execute. I wish that Allaire/Macromedia/Adobe would have come up with standard extension for this, but they didn't. IIS won't serve any files that it does not know.

Comment: @AdamCameron thanks for the advice. I've picked up a book called ColdFusion Anthology and am reading up on MVC and Seperating Logic from Layout. Hopefully it will give me some direction on this. I just don't have enough time to learn all this and then learn a framework. Also I find CFBuilder to be impossible to work with and have stuck with DW CS6 (dumped CC long ago) for my coding hence I've not made things easy for myself.

Comment: Sounds like a case of 'there is never time to do it right, but there is always time to do it twice'

Comment: The thing is... USING a framework is easy. WRITING one is hard. Don't reinvent the wheel. Use the wheel. Get the wheel running. That is part of the study involved in learning how these things work! Think of school: you don't learn by making sh!t up, you learn by following the example of the experts. Do not think you will learn anything useful by trying to write your own framework, or trying to do without one. It's the wrong approach. This is over a decade's experience talking.

Comment: Ooh, @ScottStroz: nice! And very apropos.