# Best way to deal with if/else statements

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

If you have a page which displays a lot of information to the user (e.g. customer account details) and this information needs to be different depending on who is viewing the page (e.g. manager, salesperson), I am wondering the best/efficient way to write the conditional logic.

For example I have a div which lists all the customer's personal information:

```
<cfif #User.Type# EQ "Sales"> // sales guy view
<div id="peronsonalinfo">
    <ul>
    <li>Forename Surname</li>
    <li>Address</li>
    <li>Account Status</li>
    <li>Account Manager</li>
    ..... etc etc
    </ul>
    </div>
(continues below)
```

The above is fine for a salesperson because he is not allowed to make changes to accounts. But a manager is given edit rights so he needs to get this.

```
<cfelseif #User.Type# EQ "Manager">
<div id="peronsonalinfo"> // manager view
    <form action="accountedit.cfc">
        <ul>
        <li> <input type="text" value="Forename Surname" /> </li>
        <li> <textarea value="Addres"></textarea>           </li>
        <li> <input type="text" value="Account status" /> </li>
        <li> <input type="text" value="Account manager" /> </li>
        ..... etc etc
        </ul>
    </form>
        </div>
    </cfif>
```

Please forgive the cut down code. There would probably be drop-down select elements for the account status and account manager fields. The point I'm trying to make is that there are two HTML versions of the same information depending on who you are.

What is the best way to write this kind of logic. The way I have done it seems to be repeating code so the only other alternative I can think of is to have  statements around every element, something like this?

```
 <form>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <cfif #User.Type# EQ "Sales">
                Forename Surname
                <cfelseif #User.Type# EQ "Manager">
                <input type="text" value="Forename Surname" />
              </cfif>
            </li>
            <li>
              <cfif #User.Type# EQ "Sales">
                Address
                <cfelseif #User.Type# EQ "Manager">
                <textarea value="Addres"></textarea>
              </cfif>
            </li>
            <li>
              <cfif #User.Type# EQ "Sales">
                Account Status
                <cfelseif #User.Type# EQ "Manager">
                <input type="text" value="Account status" />
              </cfif>
            </li>
            <li>
              <cfif #User.Type# EQ "Sales">
                Account Manager
                <cfelseif #User.Type# EQ "Manager">
                <input type="text" value="Account manager" />
              </cfif>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <cfif #User.Type# EQ "Manager">
            <input type="submit" value="submitform">
          </cfif>
        </form>
```

Now I'm thinking whoaaa who is getting what in all that code? What's the best way to do this and have efficient code? I am using ColdFusion 10 for my web application server but I guess this question could apply to any language.

Comment: @RowlandShaw I only included asp.net tag because I wondered what .net people's opinions would be. It doesn't matter what language you are using to answer this question.

Comment: I f I understand correctly, it looks like a M V C issue? The contents need to be pulled from one place, the functionality (access control) should be pulled from another place.

Comment: @volumeone ASP.Net people might take the opinion that you should be doing it as an ASP.Net MVC4 app with properly defined Razor views, and not to use ColdFusion; Similarly, a PHP person might favour Zend, etc...

Comment: As an aside, you don't need to wrap your variable names in `##` inside your <cf> tags, e.g. `<cfif #User.Type# EQ "Sales">` is better written as `<cfif User.Type EQ "Sales">`

Comment: @RowlandShaw is spot on insofar as both ASP and PHP devs would likely start with an MVC framework or skeleton and build their logic on top of that. In CFML, you should do the same, with FW/1 or ColdBox as your starting point.

Answer (score 5):

Have two views: one read-only, one editable. Decide which to use, based on security. Don't try to couple the security considerations within the view.

Again, as per [your other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21066750/cfincludes-best-practice-and-potential-security-concerns): you are reinventing the wheel (and ending up with a hexagon) by not simply using an MVC framework to manage all this.

This article - "[Unit Testing / TDD - why you shouldn't bother](http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2013/10/unit-testing-why-you-shouldnt-bother.html)" - is not on-topic for your question here (although you *are* using TDD, right? Or at least unit testing all your work), but the "digression" box certainly is.

Comment: even if I use an MVC framework, I still have to program the conditional logic somewhere right?

Comment: I found this resource to help me understand CF MVC principles and it confused the hell out of me. http://blog.stannard.net.au/2006/09/01/writing-your-own-simple-mvc-framework-in-coldfusion/ I get the idea of having CFCs contain my business objects. I kind of get the idea of a Controller CFC handling the logic. But what I don't get is how the presentation code is generated appropriately. at the moment my CFCs do not generate any HTML output. I thought I'd keep that in view/presentation domain.

Comment: It's entitled "Writing Your Own Simple MVC Framework in ColdFusion" You are not at the stage of doing that: you don't even understand how to write MVC code yet, let alone writing a framework (simple or otherwise). Currently you simply need to understand the MVC *concept* (which you don't which is wehy you're asking questions like the above): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller. Then just *use one of the existing frameworks*. http://fw1.riaforge.org/

Comment: Yes, you will need to write conditional logic in your controller(s). However you are not yet at the knowledge level to be concerning yourself with that. You need to down-tools and learn your craft first. *Stop writing code*. *Learn*.

Comment: Following Adam's answer, your 'logic' for determining what view file to display would be in your controller. The controller is responsible for determining what service level code to execute and what view to load. Listen to Adam. Stop coding and learn first. Most of your questions lately have shown a profound lack of understanding of the concepts with which you are trying to deal.

Comment: I hasten to add I do not mean my tone (and I know @ScottStroz is the same) to sound patronising, negative or mean-spirited. It's just honestly well-intentioned and well-informed advice for the best way for you to approach the work you're currently doing.

Comment: I appreciate it, I know its frustrating when dealing with a newbie. I found a project by Ben Nadel here https://github.com/bennadel/MVC-Learning Would this be a good starting point to understand how it fits together? I do understand the idea of MVC but I don't understand how it actually works in ColdFusion. By this I mean I understand I'll have CFCs for processing data, CFCs for logic, and then CFM view pages. I just can't find the link between how the view will display a <textbox> instead of a <p>.... sorry if this is annoying you but I can't find any examples to help me learn the basics.

Comment: Read the first three words of the answer again.  Think about your previous thread which included something about included files.

Comment: Download FW/1 or ColdBox and just RTFM. It's all explained in the docs. You don't need to "work anything out". Once you read the docs, it'll all become clear. But start with "Hello World" and work up from there. Don't try to write your current application right from word go.

Comment: OK thanks I have found this great video http://vimeo.com/46891991 from cfmeetup and have got the idea of MVC. Although its kind of strange that all mvc web applications will have very similar folder structures and files.

Comment: The similar folder structure should be expected: MVC is a design pattern that aims to leverage the general similarities between all interactive applications. All such applications have a Model (the business logic for your application, including services and domain objects), a set of Controllers (gluing the Model to the outside world by processing input and selecting views to render), and a set of Views (which are how the application displays its results).

Comment: So if I have two views: Edit.cfm and Read.cfm page for a Customer Account, I have to duplicate a lot of HTML markup in both views. Because the Read.cfm view will have exactly the same data presented except it just won't be editable. In the Edit.cfm it will allow editing of the information even though its the same information. I was thinking about using JQuery to offer some fancy UI experiences in the Edit.cfm view but with MVC its getting a bit complex at the moment.

Comment: @volumeone don't worry about views duplicating similar-looking mark-up... it's just *mark-up*: no-one cares. It's the logic one looks to not have duplicated. If you MVC yerself up proper, you'll have separate views for layout / header / nav / footer / sub-layout etc, and all that stuff will be reused. Any duplication in the display and edit "record" views then is inconsequential.